# Unable to change tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size mariadb

Tags: mariadb, my.cnf

I'm running MariaDB 10.1.47 and trying to set:

```
tmp_table_size = 64M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
```

I've set it under both the `[server]` and `[mysqld]` sections of `my.cnf`
I've tried setting it in bytes with:

```
tmp_table_size=67108864
max_heap_table_size=67108864
```

Running `systemctl restart mariadb.service && mysqladmin variables`
I still only see them both set to 50331648 (48M)
There are no other .cnf files anywhere that I can find it set to another value. Also `my.cnf` is the last config file to load so it should override all others.

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I went through my .cnf file and noticed that I had some inline comments.
Example: `skip-log-bin #Disable binary logging`

After deleting those it is now accepting my values for `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size`

What is strange is that this was only affecting those settings and none of the others in the .cnf file.

Comment: That should not affect the prevent setting on the Primary.  Were you concerned only about the Replica?

Comment: I don't have replication set up. It was affecting the Primary for some reason. I really don't know why other than the comments. After removing those, it worked.